# object hbase is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources

Tags: maven, apache-spark, hbase

I am trying to use [Spark-Hbase-Connector](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc) to get data from HBase

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase._
```

the error is

```
object hbase is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources
```

in my local `.m2` repository there already exists the `.jar` of  `org.apache.hbase.hbase-spark`... I really wonder where is this package (The Object I want to use in this package is `HBaseTableCatalog`)

the part of the `pom.xml` is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
  <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: having it in .m2 directory doesn't mean your project can use it. Your project should include that jar either through build tool or manually

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Yes I included it in `pom.xml`

Comment: can we see the part of the pom file?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Sure, I edited it as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearly mentioned in the [shc site](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc) the followings

> > `Users can use the Spark-on-HBase connector as a standard Spark package. To include the package in your Spark application use:
> >     Note: com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 has not been uploaded to spark-packages.org, but will be there soon.
> >     spark-shell, pyspark, or spark-submit
> >     $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11
> >     Users can include the package as the dependency in your SBT file as well. The format is the spark-package-name:version in build.sbt file.
> >     libraryDependencies += “com.hortonworks/shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11”`

So you will have to download the jar and include it manually in your project for the testing purpose if you are using maven.

Or you can try [maven uploaded shc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/zhzhan/shc/0.0.11-1.6.1-s_2.10)

Comment: So in maven is it G=com.hortonworks, A=shc-core, V=1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 ? I tried this and it turned out to be `Missing artifact com.hortonwork..`

Comment: please see my update, I have included the maven repo link or you can just download the jar file and use it in your project

Comment: It seems works, thanks! It is really strange that this package is not in maven central..

Comment: @RameshMaharjan where to download shc-1.1.0.2.6.3.13-5.jar ... I see only pom file in below link http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/com/hortonworks/shc/shc/1.1.0.2.6.3.13-5/

Comment: U can download SHC jars in below link https://javalibs.com/artifact/com.hortonworks.shc/shc-core